# Webots displaying processed numpy image (OpenCV Python)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, swig, webots

I am trying to simulate a line follower with Pioneer 3AT in Webots. This is the first step towards my application involving swarm robotics. I have placed camera. However, I am not able to display image processed with OpenCV in the simulation display (in realtime). For now, I am planning to just threshold the lane and display using the display node as mentioned in https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/display.

However, I am not able to get this up and running. The question is **how do I display the processed numpy image array in the webots display?**

Code that I currently have:

```
camera = Camera("camera")
camera.enable(TIME_STEP);
display = Display("display")

while (robot.step(timestep) != -1):
    cameraData = camera.getImage();
    image = np.frombuffer(cameraData, np.uint8).reshape((camera.getHeight(), camera.getWidth(), 4))
```

**Now, how do I display the `image` in `display`?**
I tried `imageNew`, `imagePaste` etc. However, I am getting plenty of C/C++ errors via SWIG and I am not able to find any relevant examples too. (The Webots simulator comes with only one example that uses display city.wbt and that uses a static image. I am not sure if that could be used. But, the summarised code of that example which is in C is as below.)

```
// speedometer
WbDeviceTag display;
int display_width = 0;
int display_height = 0;
WbImageRef speedometer_image = NULL;

// initialize display (speedometer)
if (enable_display) {
    display = wb_robot_get_device("display");
    speedometer_image = wb_display_image_load(display, "speedometer.png");
}

// display background
wb_display_image_paste(display, speedometer_image, 0, 0, false);
```

P.S.: I have spent more than 4 hours on this and I am not able to find any solution for this. There appears to be a similar question on Qt (I am not using Qt). But, that question has gone unanswered: [Ploting an image with 'imshow' of opencv in webots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556519/ploting-an-image-with-imshow-of-opencv-in-webots).
**Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am planning to opensource my entire project.**

**EDIT 1:** I tried the following as per the [following note for Java](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/display?tab=python). But, I am getting a blank display screen. No luck after 10 hours of efforts.

> **Note** [Java]: The `Display.imageNew` function can display the image returned by the `Camera.getImage` function directly if the pixel format argument is set to ARGB.

`display.imageNew(cameraData, display.ARGB, camera.getHeight(), camera.getWidth())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out an "official way" to get this up and running. However, I do not like this solution as it is not integrated directly into the simulator (and the simulations become too slow when used with this method). For now, I am accepting this answer. However, I will accept any other answer that integrates neatly into Webots.

```
cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow("preview")

while (robot.step(timestep) != -1):
    cv2.imshow("preview", image)
    cv2.waitKey(TIME_STEP)
```

**Source:** https://cyberbotics.com/forum?message=7950

Answer (score 1):

You will find more example of Display device in Webots that might help you (they are in C/C++ but you should be able to apply similar mechanisms for Python):

- projects/samples/devices/display: various example showing how to use the Display device (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-devices#display-wbt).
- projects/samples/howto/vision: uses opencv and displays the result in a Display device (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/samples-howto#vision-wbt).

In python you shoul dbe able to display an OpenCV image into the display with something similar to:

```
    imageRef = display.imageNew(camera.getImage().tolist(), Display.RGB)
    display.imagePaste(imageRef, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Could you please post a minimal working solution? I had through that before. But, I am getting SWIG errors when I try to access display memory. It looks like the C/C++ version uses `memcpy` which can't be replicated directly in Python (without digging into Webots source code).

Comment: I added an example (not tested) in the answer.

Comment: I am getting similar errors (that I used to get before) https://pastebin.com/erT8uLrT

Comment: @PrasadRaghavendra here is a tested solution:
`imageRef = display.imageNew(frame.tolist(), Display.RGB)`. @DavidMansolino please update the code

Comment: Hi @DarkoLukić thank you for the tested solution. I assume `frame = camera.getImage()` right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There is a problem only in the first line, the second is fine